# How to authenticate to a website with google authorization using curl cli

Tags: curl, post, google-authentication

How to put file in to a website if it only accepts authorization via google account?

I want to automate the upload of files to the site using curl. I parsed the form and prepared the request in the following:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" \
-d var=value \
-F "file=@tmp/file.html" \
-X POST \
https://website/s.php --insecure
```

I found the options:

```
-H "Authorization: OAuth <ACCESS_TOKEN>"
-H "Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>"
--oauth2-bearer <token>
```

But what is the process of getting a google token to access the website? What option to use it with? I could not find answers to these questions on the Internet.

Comment: Google OAuth does not authorize access to your website. You can use Google OAuth to authenticate users. Then you would write backend code that manages permissions you grant to authorized users. That is typically done in a database. Google search for examples on how to set up website login and authorization. Most frameworks have a library or plugin to do most of this for you.

Comment: @JohnHanley thanks for your answer, but I don't need to authenticate users. I need to authenticate to the site myself with my Google Account. This is not my site, it is a third party site that I have access to with my Google login. To access this site, it is not possible to create a separate login/password pair. It is possible to access only using Google Account. The question is how do I access my account on such a site.

Comment: What is the website using for authentication and authorization? Once you know that, log in to that site using their login endpoint. That is where you would fetch the token/cookie/etc used for authorization. What type of token? That depends on how they designed the site. Your question lacks the details to help you.